# Can composite operator preserve Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given a continous differentiable function $f$ on compact set $\mathcal{D}$ such that its gradient is Lipschitz continous, i.e.,
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|\leq L \|x-y\|$$
Let $g(w): = f(w^Tw)$, whether there exist constant $\delta$ such that
$$\|\nabla g(w) - \nabla g(v)\|\leq \delta \|w-v\|.$$

Comment: Where is $\delta$ used?

Comment: sorry, this is typo.

Comment: This cannot hold globally for all $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$. But if you restrict to, say, a ball of radius $R$ then yes an upper bound for the Lipschitz constant of the composition is $2(\|\nabla f\|_{C^0(\mathcal{D})} +2R^2L)$. Use the chain rule, add zeroes and use that fact that the derivative of $w\mapsto w^Tw$ is $2w$